# Autosuggest for JSON files with custom schema for Monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I use online Monaco editor sample [Configures two JSON schemas, with references](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-json-defaults)
While it works fine, in order to receive an intellisense I have to press `Ctrl+Space` (i.e. it doesn't appear automatically):

[image]
However, in VSCode (which uses Monaco), it appears instantly as soon as I type the first quotation mark:

[image]

How should I change Monaco's code sample to behave exactly as in VSCode?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, I managed to work around it by using below code:

```
this.editor.onKeyUp((e) => {
      const position = this.editor.getPosition();
      const text = this.editor.getModel().getLineContent(position.lineNumber).trim();
      if (e.keyCode === monaco.KeyCode.Enter && !text) {
        this.editor.trigger('', 'editor.action.triggerSuggest', '');
      }
    });
```

We detect the "Enter" keypress and check if we are at a new line. If yes, trigger suggestions.