# Monaco editor: intellisense for properties in square brackets not working (Typescript, works in VSCode)

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions, monaco-editor

I want to have intellisense for the following code:

```
const a = {
    asd: '123'
};
a[''] // I want the editor to suggest that there's `asd` property here
```

It works in [VS Code](https://vscode.dev):

[image]

But it doesn't work in [Monaco](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/):

[image]

I tried importing TextMate grammar from VSCode to Monaco using [monaco-tm](https://github.com/bolinfest/monaco-tm), but it seems to have no influence on intellisense.

P.S. intellisense works for dot-properties, i.e. if I type `a.`, Monaco suggests me to type `asd`.

Comment: Ok, it works in Monaco, just to trigger it one need to press 'ctrl+space' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger it automatically (without pressing 'Ctrl+Space') when you type quotes, you can use code below:

```
editor.onKeyUp((e) => {
        if (e.keyCode === monaco.KeyCode.Quote) {
          editor.trigger('', 'editor.action.triggerSuggest', '');
        }
      });
```

Thanks to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560539/autosuggest-for-json-files-with-custom-schema-for-monaco-editor) here.